# GitLab's runner without GitLab local installation

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Is it possible to use runner with project stored on GitLab.com?

Documentation says I need an 'admin' account in order to register a runner. On GitLab.com I can only set a 'Maintainer'. Beside that, it also says not to install runners on the same machine where GitLab is installed...